# Textbox value not updating

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

This is page1.html

```
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Add tags .." name="name" ng-click='gotoAddTag()' ng-model="publishMsgFormTags" required>
      </label>
```

`page2.html`

```
<a class="button button-icon icon ion-android-done" href="#" ng-click="tagSelectionDone()"></a>
```

`controller.js`

```
$scope.tagSelectionDone = function()
  {console.log("in tagSelectionDone");
    var tags="";
    angular.forEach($scope.publishMsgSelectedTags, function(v,k){
        console.log(v.text);
        tags += v.text;
    });

    $scope.publishMsgFormTags = tags;
    console.log("---->"+tags);
    console.log($scope.publishMsgFormTags);
    $location.path('publishmsg/new-message');   
  }
```

Line `$scope.publishMsgFormTags = tags;` doesn't update textbox in `page1.html` though it prints all console.log.

If print `console.log($scope.publishMsgFormTags);` it shows correct value but same value is not updating into textbox

Comment: Make sure you're using same controller in both cases.

Comment: yes i am using same controlle

Comment: Can you make a plunkr of it?  Two things that might need clarification. 

1. If you are using same controller are you sure you have the same instance? Or you have 2 instances of the same controller.

2. $location.path might reintantiate the same controller. and  $scope.publishMsgFormTags would be empty in it.